# $(R/I)[x]=R[x]/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ is a ring and $I$ an ideal of this ring, is that true that $(R/I)[x]=R[x]/I$?

Note that can $I$ be identified as a subset of $R[x]$ and we need that in order to $R[x]/I$ makes sense.

I think it's true because every polynomial $(a_0+I)+(a_1+I)x,\ldots,(a_n+I)x^n$ of $(R/I)[x]$ can be written as a polynomial of $R[x]/I$ and vice versa since we have this equality: $$(a_0+I)+(a_1+I)x,\ldots,(a_n+I)x^n=(a_0+a_1x+\ldots a_nx^n) +I$$

Is my reasoning right?

Thanks

Comment: even before going any further on your reasoning...If $I$ is an ideal of $R$ Is it necessary that $I$ is an ideal of $R[x]$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik yes of course, thank you for the remark

Comment: by "yes of course" do you mean : yes $I$ is an ideal of $R[x]$ or NO, $I$ is not an ideal of $R[x]$ :P

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik $I$ is not an ideal of $R[x]$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. First off, $I$ is not an ideal of $R[X]$ (can you see why?)

What is true is that $$(R/I)[X]\simeq R[X]/I[X]$$ where $I[X]$ denotes the ideal (can you prove it is one whenever $I$ is an ideal in $R$?) in $R[X]$ made up of polynomials with coefficients in $I$.

*Proof* Define $\eta :R[X]\to (R/I)[X]$ by mapping the polynomial $r_0+r_1X+r_2X^2+\cdots$ to the polynomial $(r_0+I)+(r_1+I)X+\cdots$. Show it is an homomorphism and find the kernel.

Comment: you are too fast.. I was expecting that he would get sometime to think of the question.. If $I$ is really an ideal of $R[x]$...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was mistaken about the ideal, you're right.

Comment: @user75086 Re: critique in first sentence: it is common (abuse of) notation to use $R/S\,$ to mean $R/RS$, i.e. to allow the quotient ideal to be implicitly specified by a generaing set. e,g, $\,\Bbb Z/n.\,$ With that convention we have $\,R[x]/I = R[x[/IR[x] = R[x]/I[x]\ \ $