# Polynomial ring is not a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I read the following post on stack exchange: [Show that $(R/I)[x]\cong R[x]/I[x]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912198/show-that-r-ix-cong-rx-ix).

However, I’m now confused. I know that polynomial rings are not fields. But suppose $I[X]$ is maximal in $R[X]$ where $I$ is an ideal in $R$ then by the above post $R/I[X]$ is a field. But this is a contradiction. So where is the flaw in this argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... therefore $I[X]$ is never maximal.